# ClassCastException using MOXy Unmarshaller with DynamicJAXBContext

Tags: xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, moxy

I am trying to follow the guide [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Dynamic/XmlToDynamicEntity) to unmarshall an XML document to a DynamicEntity. However I'm encountering a ClassCastException when I unmarshall my XML.

My code is as follows:

```
DynamicJAXBContext context = DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(DocumentGenerator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myXSD.xsd"), null, null, null);

        FileInputStream xmlInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\alexba\\myXML.xml"); 
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

        DynamicEntity statement = (DynamicEntity) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlInputStream);
```

The error is:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicEntity
```

My pom dependencies are:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
```

I've been reading the code and trying to understand how Unmarshall can ever return a DynamicEntity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MOXy will wrap the unmarshalled object in a `JAXBElement` for the same reasons that it does for a static model.  This is usually the case when the object corresponds to a named complex type.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

You can either unmarshal the object as a `JAXBElement<DynamicEntity>`:

```
JAXBElement<DynamicEntity> element = (JAXBElement<DynamicEntity>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlInputStream);
DynamicEntity statement = element.getValue();
```

Or leverage `JAXBIntrospector`:

```
DynamicEntity statement = (DynamicEntity) JAXBIntrospector.getValue( unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlInputStream));
```